# Cant get the graph to update in canvas

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In the below code i cant get the graph to update with a specific delay , so that it looks as if online update , i have used the after method to call a function which would it give it new , but still i get the whole graph at once , i also tried time.sleep even that doesnt work

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from numpy import *
from Tkinter import *
import time
from functools import partial


class Gui():



    def __init__(self,parent):


        self.parent=parent
        mL=[]
        mV=[]
        for i in range(0,10):
            ml_val=10 + i*0.1
            mv_val=1000 + i
            mL.append(ml_val)
            mV.append(mv_val)    
        frame = Frame(self.parent, width=900, height=900, bd=1)
        frame.pack()

        iframe5 = Frame(frame, bd=2,width=800, height=800, relief=RAISED)
        iframe5.pack( pady=10, padx=5)
        self.w = Canvas(iframe5, bg='white', width=600, height=510)
        self.w.pack()

        self.w.create_rectangle(1,1, 599, 509, fill="cyan")

        self.w.create_line(50,460,50,70,fill="#222")
        self.w.create_line(50, 460, 500, 460, fill="#222")
        self.w.create_text(400,55,text="mL vs mV Graph")
        self.w.create_text(390,75,text="mL : X - axis ")
        self.w.create_text(390,95,text="mV : Y - axis ")
        self.w.create_text(30,55,text="Y-Axis")
        self.w.create_text(530,480,text="X-Axis")
        y_range=450
        x_range=90

        self.y_plot=[]
        self.x_plot=[]
        for i in range(0,10):
            self.w.create_text(20,y_range,text=mV[i])
            self.w.create_text(x_range,480,text=mL[i])
            self.x_plot.append(x_range)
            self.y_plot.append(y_range)
            self.w.create_line(40,y_range,50,y_range, fill="blue")
            self.w.create_line(x_range,460,x_range,470, fill="blue")
            y_range -=40
            x_range +=40
       # time.sleep(10)
        for i in range(0,9):
            root.after(1000, partial(self.create_graph,i))        
            time.sleep(1)
    def create_graph(self,i):

        self.w.create_line(self.x_plot[i],self.y_plot[i],self.x_plot[i+1],self.y_plot[i+1], fill="blue")



if __name__== "__main__":
    root = Tk()
 #   root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
    app=Gui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `after(1000, ...)` for all the points, you are scheduling them to be drawn 1000ms after `__init__` is finished, i.e. they are all drawn at the exact same time. Adding `sleep` only delays the time when `__init__` finished, and thus the time until your UI is shown.

Instead, you should schedule the different points for *different* times after `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    # other initialization code
    for i in range(0, 9):
        root.after(1000 * i, partial(self.create_graph, i))
```

Or, put one `after` at the end of `__init__` to schedule the drawing of the first point, and another `after` in your `create_graph` method for drawing the next points.

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    # other initialization code
    # at the end, remove the for loop and instead call after
    root.after(1000, partial(self.create_graph, 0, 9))        

def create_graph(self, i, k):
    self.w.create_line(self.x_plot[i],self.y_plot[i],self.x_plot[i+1],self.y_plot[i+1], fill="blue")
    # call after again to schedule drawing more points
    if i < k:
        root.after(1000, partial(self.create_graph, i+1, 9))
```